# Power Apps: display stored procedure data in DataTable after button click

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I have just started using Power Platform (Power Apps). I recently tried to see data (via Google Sheets) in a data table which worked fine by attaching a data source (of Google Sheets) to a data table.

Now, what I am trying to do is:

1. I added a button in my Test app
2. On that button's `onSelect`, I am executing a stored procedure after successfully adding a SQL Server data source
3. The code which I wrote in `onSelect` is this:

   ```
   MyStoredProcDataOnButtonClick.Run()
   ```
4. Now, after this event is called, I want to showcase the result data from the stored procedure call in a data table
5. In the data table, I am unable to see the data source (for that stored procedure)

How can I achieve this?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Note: I created a flow for this from Power Apps to execute a stored procedure on button click.

Comment: Note that this will make the PowerApp premium.

Answer (score 0):

Add the SQL Connector to the PowerApp. Create a collection of the record(s) you need.

**Example:**

```
ClearCollect(colData,
    Filter(SQL_TABLE,
        whatever_column = whatever_value
    )
)
```

Set the `Items` property of a Gallery to `colData`. Add some Label controls to the Gallery template for the data you want to show. Like @strattonn said, the SQL Connector is premium. Though check the [PowerApps license guide](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2085130) and search for "multiplexing". Your current PowerApp-to-Flow-to-SQL workflow *may already* require all of your PowerApps users to be premium licensed.

Comment: Will the solution provided above with ClearCollect work with SP Data? Asking this because the answer mentioned is for SQL_Table and it's column-value.

Comment: I'm not following you. If you're saying **PowerApps-to-PowerAutomate-to-SQL-to-Sharepoint-back-to-PowerApps** , it won't be instantaneous. You'll likely need to put a pause in the app to let the data load.